# load a different font file for each font-weight configuration (with tailwind)

Tags: fonts, tailwind-css

I have a SofiaPro-SemiBold.woff2 file which I would like to use when I enter the class name "font-semibold" with tailwind. For the moment, it seems that tailwind automatically calculate the letter to print with the new font-weight from the default font file (normal way to do actually).
It must be a classical question but what is the best way to do this ?

Thanks for your help.